# Simulate button presses with guitar frequency c#

Tags: c#, button, frequency, simulate, guitar

I've been playing Rocksmith lately with my guitar and I find it really interesting. The way I believe they 'know' which fret you're pressing is by comparing the frequency of the note to the note that you're supposed to be pressing.

I have an idea for a way to play Guitar Hero PC with a traditional guitar, too (albeit very weird). Essentially it would work the same as the normal guitar hero controller, but with a real guitar.

I could take note of the frequency of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th fret, on the low E string, which would be the 5 buttons on the controller.

This would serve two functions:
1) Each time the code registers a frequency, it will also register a 'pluck' as you can't really get a frequency without plucking (other than tapping).

2) It would also allow me to assign each frequency to a button press.

I haven't started implementing this yet so I hope it doesn't violate the format of SO. Essentially why I'm making this is to ask, is it feasible? What are the drawbacks? Has it been implemented before? Do you have any tips on the way to implement this? Etc.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could make a start by learning about how to recover frequency from a waveform using Fourier Transforms.  Try getting something simple going before you go further.  One point, however, is whether you intend to match the fingering.  Obviously there are many ways to achieve the same note on a guitar, but they have subtly different overtones.  Matching more than primary frequency could be rather tricky.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044289/how-to-find-the-fundamental-frequency-of-a-guitar-string-sound?rq=1

Comment: There's an epic response by Eric Lippert regarding the 'inverse' problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974531/writing-musical-notes-to-a-wav-file worth a read as background.

Comment: There would probably be too much latency for this to work - button presses are instantaneous - reliably detecting the pitch of a note could take > 100 ms.