# Looking for guitar string wav files

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, guitar

I've seen several references to a wav file of a guitar string called "dist_gtr_6.wav" in python examples.

I'm researching pitch estimation and wonder if this and the other string companion files are available for download.

Here is one reference:

[How to find the fundamental frequency of a guitar string sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044289/how-to-find-the-fundamental-frequency-of-a-guitar-string-sound)

Any tips to find this wav file?

Comment: How difficult is to record it?

Comment: I don't have access to a guitar and pickup now.  Will in a few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, at least legally. From my research, that file is included in this commercial software package:

http://www.wavesgtr.com/html/product_gtr3.html

You can buy it [here](http://www.wavesgtr.com/html/buy.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not opposed to purchasing from wavesgtr but I don't know which package this file is in.  Any ideas?

Comment: Oops, thanks you answered the question directly.

Comment: BTW, tough crowd with the down votes.  I guess people were thinking I wanted to pirate the file, which I was not.