# How to extract bass/mid/trebel frequencies

Tags: python, audio, numpy, analysis

I have done an FFT transform on the individual frames extracted from a WAV file. The spectral values don't really make much sense, and would like to know how to isolate the bass/med/treble frequencies. The cutoffs between those frequencies are arbitrary and will be set by me.

I would like to know what code I can use to isolate the intensity of bass/med/treble frequencies if given a numpy array of the full spectral range

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: Can you show some code on how you currently make it work? This helps us to get a solution for your problem (and because im very interested in doing something similar as well)

Comment: this may give you some hint: [how to find the fundamental frequency of a guitar string sound](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5045834/832621)

Comment: "The spectral values don't really make much sense ..."  In what way?  You doubt the accuracy of the FFT?  Are you familiar with digital filters?