# Autocorrelation and Fundamental Frequency

Tags: python, algorithm, signal-processing

I am trying to figure out fundamental frequency of sound

I try to detect fundamental frequency with autocorrelation.

I found this code:

```
corr = np.correlate(signal, signal, mode='full')
maxcorr = np.argmax(corr)
corr = corr / corr[maxcorr]
corr = corr[corr.size / 2:]
```

I got this graph from the code above:
    [image]

index of maximum value is 3145.
and my sample rate is 44100.

so... I got fundamental frequency 44100/3145 = 14.02.

This is way too wrong since the sound is Piano C4 which should be around 261Hz.

How can I get fundamental frequency with autocorrelation?

**ADDED:**

this is a graph of C4 of piano
[image]

Comment: Is your data simulated? I see no sign of noise which is not normal for real data. I would check the data first: plot it and make sure it is a sinewave with expected frequency...

Comment: Related question that may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044289/how-to-find-the-fundamental-frequency-of-a-guitar-string-sound?rq=1

Comment: I'd recommend plotting against `t = np.arange(corr.size) / 44100` for clarity

Comment: @JulienBernu I added C4 sound. this sound is extracted from Guitar Pro